# Android's SQLite date comparison

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I need to compare a column called `end_date` with the current date but I believe the where and order clause are wrong, since I'm getting no results. The way I do it in `MySQL` is this one:

```
WHERE mytable.end_date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY mytable.end_date DESC
```

This works in `MySQL`. Needless to say, `end_date` **is not** a `VARCHAR` but a date field (can't remember which one at the moment

This is what I got in `SQLite`:

```
WHERE date(mytable.end_date) >= date('now') ORDER BY date(mytable.end_date) DESC
```

What am I doing wrong?

**PS**: the query works without the where and order by clause and both database have the same data, the only difference is `SQLite` fields are `TEXT`

**EDIT:** date format goes like this `Jul 28 11:30:31 EST 2014` which is `EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy`

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `end_date` column?

Comment: date format comes like this "Jul 28 11:30:31 EST 2014"

Answer (score 0):

The [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) work only with one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Use the `yyyy-MM-dd` format, then you don't need to call the `date()` function.